Rotate modelinstance about its own local y axis
What is the correct approach to rotate a modelinstance around its own y-axis in LiBGDX ?
Neither of the following is working!
//approach 1
Matrix4 mat4 = new Matrix4();
mat4.set(gameMainPlayerReference.transform);
mat4.rotate(Vector3.Y,-1f*playerRotationSpeed*deltatime);
gameMainPlayerReference.transform.set(mat4);

//approach 2
gameMainPlayerReference.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y,-1f*playerRotationSpeed*deltatime);

in both approaches, the modelinstance rotates about the cirumference of an imaginary circle. NOT, its own local y-axis(should be in the middle of object).
